# java.lang.NumberFormatException usando jsonObject.optString()

Tags: android, string

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema solo en ciertas ocaciones. La app trae información de una url externa mediante una petición Volley tomando los datos de un archivo php con datos json. De 900 dispositivos tuve problema en 17, es poco pero un error hay. Mayormente los errores provienen de dispositivos Galaxy.

El bloqueo lo veo desde playConsole:

```
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt (Integer.java:620)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt (Integer.java:643)
  **at com.miapp.yamil.miapp.jugar.onResponse (jugar.java:319)
  at com.miapp.yamil.miapp.jugar.onResponse (jugar.java:42)**
  at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse (JsonRequest.java:83)
  at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run (ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:251)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6589)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

En estas lineas tengo una conversión de String a Int

```
   *numero.setText(relleneo.getNumero());
    numeros=Integer.parseInt(numero.getText().toString());*
```

numero proviene de la consulta volley y es rellenado

```
*relleneo.setNumero(jsonObject.optString("CodPreg"));*
```

No logro detectar cual es el problema ya que sucede solo cada cierto tiempo.

Not: Agrego, los usuarios me comentaron que cuando sucede esto la app se detiene y cierra sola.

Comment: Revisa CodPreg de tu archivo Json. La excepción ocurre porque el formato numérico no es el adecuado.

Comment: Pocos datos das...¿puedes reproducir el error intentando usar la aplicación con la red deshabilitada?

Comment: Me e fijado en eso, el caso es que no siempre sucede  muy pocas veces, la app recarga constantemente esta consulta e estado media hora recargando esto y no genero error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el valor que tratas de convertir en ocasiones no es un valor numérico, ya que el json en ocasiones no tiene ese valor.

Recuerda el uso de [**optString(String name)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String)), si el valor que tratas de obtener no existe este método retorna una cadena vacía (`""`), este valor obviamente no es numérico.

Puedes usar esta otra versión del método [**optString()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

[public String optString (String name, 
                String fallback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

y usarla de esta forma definiendo un valor default en caso de no encontrar valor, por ejemplo "0", este valor sería convertido sin problema a entero:

```
relleneo.setNumero(jsonObject.optString("CodPreg", "0"));
```

---

Otra opción es validar si el valor es numérico, si no es numérico definir un valor default que sea numérico, usando el siguiente método:

```
public static int esNumerico(String number){
    int result = 0; //valor default.
    try{
        if(number != null){
            result = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

usarías el método de esta forma:

```
  numeros=Integer.parseInt(esNumerico(numero.getText().toString()));
```